# Trouble implementing the comparable interface

Tags: java

I keep getting the error: Student is not abstract and does not override abstract method compareTo(java.lang.Object) in java.lang.Comparable

Why is this?  What this is trying to accomplish is taking a list of students and comparing them by GPA.

```
public class Student implements Comparable
    {
        private String name;
        private double gpa;    
        public Student(String name, double gpa)
        {
            this.name = name;
            this.gpa = gpa;
        }    
        public String getName()
        {
            return name;
        }
        public double getGpa()
        {
            return gpa;
        }    
        public String toString()
        {
            return "Name: " + name + "  GPA: " + gpa;
        }
        public double compareTo(Object other)
        {
            Student filler = (Student)other;
            if(this.getGpa() < filler.getGpa())
                return -1;
            else if(this.getGpa() == filler.getGpa())
                return 0;
            else
                return 1;
        }    
    }
```

Comment: Side note, read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2770321/what-is-a-raw-type-and-why-shouldnt-we-use-it

Comment: `Comparable#compareTo` has a return type of `int`, not `double`.

Comment: `compareTo()` must return an `int`. Also, you should learn enough about generics to use them with this code.

Comment: Ok I see.  I don't know why but I typed double without thinking.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3451158 When you implement an interface, be sure to check the documentation for the method signatures. They must match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

```
public double compareTo(Object other)
```

should be

```
@Override
public int compareTo(T other)
```

Take a look at the [`Comparable`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) interface. It requires a method called `compareTo`, that takes an argument of type `T` (generic parameter), **that returns an `int`**. The method you have created doesn't implement the method specified in the interface, which is why the Java compiler is complaining.

Since the `Comparable` interface is genericized, you should take advantage of generics and make your class implement `Comparable<Student>`. When you do that, the signature of `compareTo` becomes:

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Student other)
```

Which is better than a raw `Object`, since you don't have to cast, and more importantly, you don't accidentally end up passing in something that is not a `Student`.

One more thing: use the `@Override` annotation when you implement methods from the interface. Assuming you're using a halfway-decent IDE, you would have seen an error if you had:

```
@Override
public double compareTo(Object other)
```

Since there is no method with that signature in the interface.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question directly, you need to change the return type of `compareTo()` from `double` to `int`.

There are also several other modifications you should make to improve your code:

1. implement `Comparable<Student>` instead of just `Comparable`. This makes it so you can write `public int compareTo(Student other)` and only allows calling `compareTo()` with other `Student` references.
2. Add `@Override` annotations before both `toString()` and `compareTo()`. This annotation helps you avoid some common errors which the compiler cannot catch.

Answer (score 0):

[compareTo](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo(T)) method returns an `int` and not a `double`.

Also using an `Override` annotation helps to be sure that you are overriding the method correctly. So change this

```
public double compareTo(Object other)
```

to

```
@Override
public int compareTo(Object other)
```